# Multiple conditions (and operator) in XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<bookstore>
    <books>
        <book name="book1" title="Title 1" author="Author 1"/>
        <book name="book2" title="Title 2" author="Author 2"/>
        <book name="book3" title="Title 1" author="Author 2"/>
    </books>

    <myBooks>
        <book name="Test1" title="Title 1" author="Author 1"/>
        <book name="Test2" title="Title 2" author="Author 1"/>
        <book name="Test3" title="Title 1" author="Author 2"/>
    </myBooks>
</bookstore>
```

I want to get all `name` of `book` in `myBooks` that have not a corresponding `book` in `books` (title and author).

So, for the example, I want to retrieve: the book `"Test2"` because the pair `("Title  2", "Author 1")` does not exist in `books`.

So far, I have:

```
//myBooks/book[not(@title = //books/book/@title and @author = //books/book/@author)]
```

But, of course, in that case, the above XPath does not work because the combination ("Title  2", "Author 1") exists (from "book2" and "book1").

How can I apply the `and` operator on the same node?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on the version of XPath.

You can't do this in a single XPath 1.0 expression because it would require a structure like

```
/bookstore/myBooks/book[/bookstore/books/book[
                  @title = _outer-predicate_/@title and
                  @author = _outer-predicate_/@author]]/@name
```

i.e. you'd need to capture the book being tested by the outer predicate so you can compare it to the inner one.  Pure XPath 1.0 doesn't support this, you'd have to iterate over the content of `myBooks` yourself (e.g. with an `xsl:for-each`, as you've tagged your question "xslt").

In XPath 2.0 you *can* do it in one expression with an explicit quantifier

```
/bookstore/myBooks/book[not(some $book in /bookstore/books/book satisfies
       ($book/@author = @author and $book/@title = @title))]/@name
```

Comment: The XPath 2.0 version is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can concatenate attribute values using `concat()` and compare them:

```
//myBooks/book[not(concat(@*[name() = "title" or name() = "author"], ",") = concat(//books/book/@*[name() = "title" or name() = "author"], ","))]
```

For every `book` in `myBook` it gets the concatenation of `title` and `author` attributes and compares it with the same concatenation for every `book` in `books`.

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)):

```
$ xmllint input.xml --xpath '//myBooks/book[not(concat(@*[name() = "title" or name() = "author"], ",") = concat(//books/book/@*[name() = "title" or name() = "author"], ","))]'
<book name="Test2" title="Title 2" author="Author 1"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming XSLT I would define a key `<xsl:key name="book" match="books/book" use="concat(@title, '|', @author)"/>` and then in the predicate you can check `[not(key('book', concat(@title, '|', @author)))]`.